# Performance/Load test using selenium webdriver prerecorded steps

Tags: selenium, testing, performance-testing, load-testing

I have been using selenium webdriver as my main method to do functional tests. So far its been working greate with our product.

I need to do some performance and/or load tests on the website, I was wondering if there is a tool that would incorporate my selenium tests or a tool which i can use with the recorded tests as the base.

Currently i am using selenium webdriver with C#

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The best option, imho, is using Apache Jmeter to record and replay performance tests. There is a webdriver plugin for Jmeter to record EUX (end user experience) but it does not support the recorded Selenium IDE  webdriver scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have tests written in C# the most obvious way would be using [Visual Studio Load Testing](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing) capabilities.

If you are looking for a free and open-source solution I would recommend going for [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). JMeter has integration with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) so you should be able to run your Selenium tests in multi-threaded manner. However you will need to convert your C# code into one of the WebDriver Sampler supported languages (default is JavaScript)

[image: JMeter WebDriver Sampler Languages]

Remember that Selenium tests are very resource-intensive as real browsers consume a lot of CPU/RAM so the number of virtual users you will be able to mimic this way will be very limited. So recommended approach is creating main load on a HTTP protocol level and use one Selenium instance to check rendering speed while your application is under the load.

You can install WebDriver Sampler plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

[image: JMeter Selenium WebDriver Sampler Installation]

Comment: Thanks Man the Jmeter with selenium sounds like an amazing solution. I am going to try that. I have tried the VS load test but it didnt really suite me since with selenium it opens a number of browser similar to the number of users you wish to do the test with. Ex: If the test is done on 50 users then 50 browsers will open. Too heavy on my machines.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to run full browsers.  HTTP layer tests are far simpler?  You also should be looking at only a subset of business processes in performance which generate a preponderance of load.